# SharePoint ModalDialog Callback

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, callback

I have a function that runs on page load that displays some content.

loadTopSupportArticles();

On my SharePoint page I have a button that when clicked runs this:

```
var pageUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
function addTopArticleItem() {
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(
    {
        url: pageUrl + "/Content/Lists/topsupportarticles/NewForm.aspx",
        width: 500,
        height: 500,

    }
);
}
```

This opens the new item dialog and I'm able to add a new item...

How can I provide a callback that then reloads the data in the page?  Not a full page refresh just reloads my data...

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To provide a callback function, use the `dialogReturnValueCallback` property of the options object that you pass to `showModalDialog()`, as in the example code below.

```
var pageUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
function addTopArticleItem() {
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(
    {
        url: pageUrl + "/Content/Lists/topsupportarticles/NewForm.aspx",
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        dialogReturnValueCallback: myCallbackFunction
    });
}

// The callback function expects a parameter of type SP.UI.DialogResult
function myCallbackFunction(result){
    switch(result){
        case SP.UI.DialogResult.OK:
            alert("You clicked OK");
            // reload data as necessary here
            break;
        case SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel:
            alert("You clicked cancel or close.");
            break;
    }
}
```